# Combining 2d arrays to 3d initialization error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I know how to combine 2 2d arrays into a 3d. I did something like this:

```
a = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
b = np.arange(26,51).reshape(5,5)
c = np.stack((a,b))
```

That seems to work fine. The problem is I need to iterate over a loop to stack multiple 2d arrays and I need to input the number of such 2d arrays(i.e. the # is unknown).

So I did:

```
t = np.array([]).reshape(0,5,5)
t = np.stack((t,a)) #loop over each 2d array represented by a
```

I am getting this error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 t = np.stack((t,a))
>
> <**array_function** internals> in stack(*args, **kwargs)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py
>   in stack(arrays, axis, out)
>       423     shapes = {arr.shape for arr in arrays}
>       424     if len(shapes) != 1:
>   --> 425         raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
>       426 
>       427     result_ndim = arrays[0].ndim + 1
>
> ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape

Any suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: Combine them into one list, and do just one `stack`.  It more efficient, and easier to get right.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I did this:

```
data = np.empty((0,25))
data = np.vstack((data,one_row(random.randint(1, 3)))) #one_row returns a 1d array
input_data = np.reshape(input_data,(num_samples,5,5))
```